# insert a std::initializer_list into std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdmap

I have a method like this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> container;

void myMap(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, int>> input)
{
    // insert 'input' into map...
}
```

I can call that method like this:

```
myMap({
    {"foo", 1}
});
```

How I can convert my custom argument and insert into the map?

I tried:

```
container = input;

container(input);
```

But don't work because the parameter of map is only `std::initializer_list` and there's no `std::pair` there.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
container.insert(input.begin(), input.end());
```

If you want to *replace* the contents of the map. do `container.clear();` first.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the value_type of *std::map<std::string,int>* is not
*std::pair<std::string,int>*. It is *std::pair<const std::string, int>*. Note the *const* on the key. This works fine:

```
std::map<std::string, int> container;

void myMap(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, int>> input) {
    container = input;
}
```

If you can't change your function's signature, you have to write a loop or use *std::copy* to convert each input element into the value_type of the container. But I'm guessing you probably can, since it's called *myMap* and not *otherGuysMap* :) .